# Cluster nodes need to read different sections of an input file - how do I organize it?

Tags: io, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I am trying to read an input file in a cluster environment. Different nodes will read different parts of it. However the parts are not clearly separated, but interleaved in a "grid".

For example, a file with 16 elements (assume integers):

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 A B
C D E F
```

If I use four nodes, the first node will read the top left 2x2 square (`0,1,4,5`), the second node will read the top right 2x2 square and so on.

How should I handle this? I can use MPI or OpenMP. I have two ideas but I don't know which would work better:

1. Each node will open the file and have its own handle to it. Each node would read the file independently, using only the part of the file it needs and skipping over the rest of it. In this case, what would be the difference between using `fopen` or `MPI_File_open`? Which one would be better?
2. Use one node read the whole file and send each part of the input to the node that needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your question,

I will not suggest the second option you mentioned. that is using one node to read and then distributing the parts. Reasons being this is slow .. especially if the file is large. Here you have twice the overhead, first to keep other processes waiting and second to send the data which is read.  So clearly a no go for me.

Regarding your first option, there is no big difference between using fopen and MPI_Fole_open. But Here I will still suggest MPI_File_open to avail certain facilities like non blocking I/O operations and Shared file pointers (makes life easy)